# What’s a bi triplet when referring to $\rm eV$?

Tags: terminology, quantum-electrodynamics, laser

What is a bi triplet? Is that 2x3=6? I’m reading a paper on 2 separate frequency lasers pumping a silicon wafer. And the measurements of energy in the silicon are then given as: “a bi triplet at 0.65eV”.
Presumably the 0.65eV is also referring to a wavelength of 1907.4nm.
But what exactly is a “bi triplet at 0.65eV”?

It’s in a Nature april 2023 open access article called “[Orbital-Resolved observation of singlet fission](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-05814-1)”. Bi Triplet is mentioned several times in several different ways on the abstract and first page. For instance in the abstract it says

> by transforming a singlet exciton into two triplet excitons and thereby doubling the number of excited charge carriers.

The measurement of 0.65eV is said to be the bitriplet (3 excitons) How does one measurement of 0.65eV become 3 excitons?. Is an ‘exciton’ just a theoretical assumption?

Comment: We appreciate your clarifying edits; some comments requesting those clarifications have been removed.